# How can I detect if the first nodeType inside a <li> is a nodeType 1 followed by nodeType 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way to detect if a hyperlink is the first node of a `<li>`.

For instance if I have:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="file.pdf">hyperlink</a> Text text text text...</li>
    <li>Text text text text <a href="file.pdf">hyperlink</a>...</li>
</ul>
```

I need to find a way to detect that the first element/node inside the `<li>` is the link to the PDF. If the hyperlink is after the nodeType 3 (text) it should not pass the verification.

Given that, what I'm trying to accomplish is to assign a class to the `<li>` that stats with a hyperlink by using:

```
.closest('li').addClass('myclass');
```

So far what I got is:

```
$('li').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 1;
}).closest('li').addClass('myclass');
```

Which doesn't do what I want.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you want the first `<li>` in your example to have the class, but not the second?

Comment: [You might find this useful](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: That's correct @MikeMcCaughan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you're filtering the contents on whether *any* of the nodes have a `nodeType` of `1`, which would collect both `li`s. It sounds like you want to find if the first node is a link, which you'll need to find for each `li`.

```js
    $('li').filter(function(idx, li) {
      return $(li).contents().first().is('a');
    }).addClass('myclass');
```

```css
.myclass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="file.pdf">hyperlink</a> Text text text text...</li>
  <li>Text text text text <a href="file.pdf">hyperlink</a>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good catch, it can also filter the `.pdf` anchors if OP wants only them: `return $(li).contents().first().is('a[href$=".pdf"]');`

Comment: So will this be correct:

`$('li, li > strong').filter(function(idx, li) {
        return $(li).contents().first().is(
            'a[href$=".pdf"], a[href$=".PDF"]',
            'a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".JPG"]'
        );
    }).closest('li').addClass('li');`

It seem to be working. I still have to test it around the site.

THANKS A LOT guys for helping out!!!

(Sorry, I'm not sure how to format this reply in different lines)

Answer (score 0):

So to cover:

```
<li><strong><a href="file.pdf">hyperlink</a> Text text text text...<strong></li>
```

And other if the file extension is capitalize (PDF) I can do the following as well?

```
$('li, li > strong').filter(function(idx, li) {
    return $(li).contents().first().is(
        'a[href$=".pdf"], a[href$=".PDF"]',
        'a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".JPG"]'
    );
}).closest('li').addClass('li');
```

I also had to add `.closest('li')` to have this working for other `<li>`'s that started with a hyperlink.

Thank you all for the help!